# Using WordPress User Details outside Directory

Tags: wordpress

I have a PHP Web App in which I want to use some User Details from WordPress installed inside a Folder.
Suppose My App will be inside ===>>> **www.example.com** 
and my WordPress install will be inside ===>>> **www.example.com/membership**.
Basically I will check if User is Logged-In in WordPress and use some values 
from WordPress Database to restrict Few Settings in my Web App.
I anyways need WordPress for Blogging purpose so thinking of using its User 
Registration and 
Log-In module as well.
Possible ?

Comment: Possible? Sure. Being logged in is stored in a cookie, you need to make a call to WP to verify its authentic and get whatever values you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can utilize wp in your app in following way:

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require(__DIR__'/membership/wp-blog-header.php');
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, But this won't work.You need the change the path of cookies to root folder.